# Create smoke container to link other docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to create a smoke container to link other docker container.
Basically I have multiple container which are link to each other
I am trying to create a smoke container where i can run some script to check if each container and there port are up after docker-compose up.

Following are the 2 solution which i tried
a) Running a python script to fetch ip and port from  ( /etc/hosts) and then check if socket ( ip:host) is accessible. (/etc/hots) does not give me desire return.

b) Running a python script which fetch ip and host using (docker inspect) which gives all container ip. Problem with this is i need to have docker installed inside one of the docker container which is not a good solution

How do I achieve my goal.

Comment: maybe you search something like kubernetes. its a wrapper around docker-container. no need for docker-compose and you have full access to all informations insideand outside your docker containers. https://kubernetesbootcamp.github.io/kubernetes-bootcamp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-2) of the Compose spec, then your service containers will all run inside a Docker network. You can create your smoke test container in the same network and access containers by name, you don't need to find the IP address.

Take this sample compose file which represents a distributed system:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
```

If the YAML file is in a directory called `myapp` when you run `docker-compose u p -d`, Compose will create a network called `myapp_default`, and create containers for the services in that network:

```
> docker-compose up -d                                                                                              
Creating network "myapp_default" with the default driver                                                            
Creating myapp_redis_1                                                                                              
Creating myapp_web_1
```

Now you can run a separate container and join it to that network - so your smoke test doesn't need to be part of the compose file. Inside the network you can reach containers by their name, which is built from `{app-name}_{service-name}_{instance-number}`.

As a simple example, I can use an image with some utilities installed and just ping those containers:

```
> docker run -it --rm --network myapp_default sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils

root@000db50df537:/# ping -c 1 myapp_web_1                                                                          
PING myapp_web_1 (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                 
64 bytes from myapp_web_1.myapp_default (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.423 ms                               

root@000db50df537:/# ping -c 1 myapp_redis_1                                                                        
PING myapp_redis_1 (172.19.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                               
64 bytes from myapp_redis_1.myapp_default (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.340 ms
```